# Numerical string withing another string

Tags: regex

What will be the regular expression to find a numerical string starting with a number other than 0 and having a length of 13 or more. This numerical string would be a substring inside a bigger alphanumeric string.

Comment: Try `[1-9][0-9]{12,}`

Answer (score -2):

```
/[1-9][0-9]{12,}/
```

You're looking for a number from 1 to 9, then for 12 or more numbers from 0 to 9.